# Get json value using regex in linux

Tags: json, bash, command-substitution

I have a json file **file.json** like this:

```
{
  "abc": "123",
  "def": 456,
  "ghi": 789
}
```

I am trying to get value of all the keys using regex in bash terminal.

Here is what I tried for getting value of **abc**:

```
var=cat file.json
regex='(abc\":) \"(.+)\",'
[[ $var =~ $regex ]]
echo ${BASE_REMATCH[1]}
```

It doesn't print anything. I am trying to get/print value of **abc** i.e. **"123"**

Please note that I can't use jq parser.

Comment: Use proper tools to parse json, i.e. `jq`

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano, I don't have jq available on linux machine where I am trying to use it.

Comment: One cannot put a screw with a hammer. If you cannot use jq to parse JSON within shell, then check other available languages with JSON parsing support. Python, PHP, Perl have it natively. And if none is available to you, then get the machine administrator to install the tool you need for the job you need to perform. If you are an employee, a contractor or a student, it is up to your employer, customer or school to provide you with the tools you need.

Comment: The marked duplicate shows answer in jq, grep, jsawk, python, node, sed. Please find your personal favorite there.

Answer (score 0):

While it is generally advised to use a Json parser (*don't badly do work that has already be well done by someone else*) It is sometimes just OK to parse Json via regex for *use-and-throw-away* scripts, or for parsing very simple json files/strings (like the one you used in your input)

If that is your case, this **may** work for you (as long as the values are scalars)

```
var=$(cat file.json)
regex='"abc"[[:space:]]*:[[:space:]]*("([^"]+|\\")+"|[^[:space:],"]+)'

[[ $var =~ $regex ]]

if [[ $var =~ $regex ]]; then
  echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
fi
```

For any other cases, use a json parser.

Perl is installed on almost every Linux flavour, and the module JSON::PP should be part of the core modules.

So you could do something like this:

```
perl -MJSON::PP -E '$j=decode_json <>; say $j->{abc}' -0777 file.json
```